# I need a powershell script to use zmodem for file transfer in microsoft IIS.

Tags: powershell, zmodem

I want to use powershell to do file transfer, but I have to use zmodem. Is there a powershell script for this? I know no better way to exchange data using php in a Windows/IIS environment.

Comment: I think rs232xfer will serve my purposes. Are there any other options?

Comment: no one answered so i am closing this.

Answer (score 1):

use rs232xfer to communicate with modem, skip powershell since it has no pre-made zmodem script